# Is there anyway to watch wmv and or divx videos on android?

Tags: nexus-one, video

I have a nexus one and would love to watch divx and wmv videos on it. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

The only one I'm aware of is [yxflash](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.kr-mobilesoft-yxflash-qEnD.aspx), and I wasn't too impressed by it - the video was quite choppy. I am looking forward to the upcoming Android version of [CorePlayer](http://coreplayer.com/), though, because I was able to play smooth DivX videos with its predecessor TCPMP on my Tungsten T5 with a fraction of the power my Nexus One had.

**edit:** I just saw that there's a new media player out for Android called [RockPlayer](http://rockplayer.freecoder.org/index_en.html) that will play DivX and WMV. I haven't had a chance to test it though.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed RockPlayer from the Android Market on my Nexus One, limited testing for avi, divx and mkv formats has been successful. Have yet to check wmv's.

Comment: +1 on RockPlayer. I've used it for quite a while and it has been great. Combined with UPnPlay, I can watch just about anything on my home media server.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it with both [arcMedia](https://market.android.com/details?id=sns.arcMedia.playerInterface.arm6) and [MoboPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil) to view these.  WMVs play fine with this.

An alternative is do send it to your gmail and watch it from the gmail app or to upload it to Picasa and view it in the Gallery or through the browser.  In both cases the video is converted in transit to something the video player understands.

Comment: Really? That's an awesome work around given the hassle of video conversion. Will have to give it a go...